# Elasticsearch - which type of query should be used

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch document with source like below:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "id": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "make": "Ford",
        "model": "Mustang",
        "color": "Red"
    }
}
```

I would like to write a query that will match phrases like below:

- Ford
- Ford Mustang
- Mustang
- Mustang Ford
- ford mustang

but will not match phrase like:

- Ford Audi Mustang
- Audi Mustang

What type of query should be used in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, first you need to query only on **make** and **model** fields. Next you need to set a proper analyzer for the query string that you pass. In this case, [whitespace analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) makes more sense. So here is the query that you can use:

```
query_string: {
  query: {
    fields: ['make', 'model']
    analyzer: 'whitespace'
    query: 'Ford Mustang'   
  }
}
```

Comment: It works correctly after adding: **"default_operator": "and"** to query (I don't want 'ford audi mustang' to match) and making query phrase lowercase ('ford mustang' instead of 'Ford Mustang'). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean musts:

Search any field:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/cars_index/car_type/_search' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"Ford"}}, {"query_string":{"query":"mustang"}}]}}}'
```

Search specific fields:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/cars_index/car_type/_search' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"make:Ford"}}, {"query_string":{"query":"model:mustang"}}]}}}'
```

You can use combination of musts, shoulds, must_not etc. as well as do negations on fields:

```
{"query":"-make:Ford"} (not make == Ford)
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: This is true only when I know that 'Ford' is a make and 'mustang' is a model, but my search input is one phrase containing make and/or model, like 'Ford Mustang', 'Mustang Ford' or 'Ford Audi'. The latter should not match.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with:

```
BoolQueryBuilder q = boolQuery();
for (String word : phrase.split("\\s+")) {
    q.must(boolQuery()
        .should(matchQuery("make", word))
        .should(matchQuery("model", word))
        .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
    );
}
```

but I'm splitting search phrase and use its words to build a query.

Is there a better way to do it?